# Body background color changing using webkit causes glitches

Tags: html, css, background, webkit

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body
{
font-family:'main';
font-size:12px;
background:#180153;
-webkit-animation:liveback 100s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes liveback
{
0% {background: #180153;}
10% {background: #ad004b;}
20% {background: #7a1c00;}
30% {background: #09664c;}
40% {background: #5e6609;}
50% {background: #9e0b0b;}
60% {background: #9e0b92;}
70% {background: #0023b0;}
80% {background: #2e9100;}
90% {background: #ad8540;}
100% {background: #180153;}
}
</style>
<body> ...<table width=200% style="background:transparent;"><tr><td>..</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I have horizontal scrolling on my page (cause the table inside has a width of 200%).. maybe this is causing a problem on my website, only that part of the body having height and width of your browser window..update the new background color.! Have a look at this image, % values may be wrong w.r.t colors:1.[First screenshot (Zoom=25%)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iUmE.png) 2.[Second screenshot (Zoom=100%)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clo1p.png)
Visit www.harshalgajjar.tk to have a look at the table.

Comment: http://harshalgajjar.tk/index_liveback.html Link for viewing problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's right the problem is the width of 200%

I think you can create a walk around using an intermediate DIV like so:

**CSS:**

```
@-webkit-keyframes liveback {
  0% {background: #180153;}
  10% {background: #ad004b;}
  20% {background: #7a1c00;}
  30% {background: #09664c;}
  40% {background: #5e6609;}
  50% {background: #9e0b0b;}
  60% {background: #9e0b92;}
  70% {background: #0023b0;}
  80% {background: #2e9100;}
  90% {background: #ad8540;}
  100% {background: #180153;}
}
body {
  width: 100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  font-family:'main';
  font-size:12px;
  background:#180153;
  -webkit-animation:liveback 100s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}

.outer-table{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; //or whatever you need
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<body>
  <div class="outer-table">
    <table width=200% height=50% style="background:none;"><tr><td>..</td></tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

Note: the `table` is not the problem, just having a `body` with a  `width: 200%;` would create the same problem